# SQL Server 2014 - Find Lower Nearest Number from the available Sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find a value in the table that is the nearest to a given value.

So, for example, Values:

```
40, 42, 45, 48, 51, 53, 55, 58
```

Select the nearest value to 50. Obviously in the above example it would be 51. However, with this series:

```
40, 42, 45, 48, 53, 55, 58, 60
```

The lower nearest value is 48.

If I have 52, 52 is already available and so I need to pick.

I tried using Select Top(1) from table order by number DESC but it is fetching multiple values.

Comment: If I told you there was a function for getting Absolute Value, could you figure it out from there?

Comment: What kind of top 1 selects more than 1 row? Could you include that too..

Comment: @JamesZ `with ties`, but that's not what is going on here. Just had to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `abs()`:

```
select top 1 value
from t
order by abs(51 - value);
```